# Safe to delete Sitecore master/web old index after rebuild/swap?

Tags: indexing, azure-search

We're using the `Swap and Rebuild feature` of `Sitecore 9.1` when we need to rebuild our indexes for `Azure Search`. Occasionally, after the rebuild and swap is complete; Sitecore won't delete the old search index, even though it's been a day or so later.

I've confirmed in the `index_catalog index` that Sitecore is pointing to the newly created index; the older index is marked as REBUILD.

I've confirmed that the older index is no longer being used. So is it safe to delete? The reason I'm asking is sometimes we're running up against Azure's index quota when these older unused indexes aren't being used any longer and aren't cleaned up.